# debian puppet clients (0.24.5-3) failing to retrieve file , centOs (0.25.5-1) working ok

Tags: debian, puppet, debian-lenny

I have got a puppetmaster and a mix of CentOs 5.4 and Lenny 5.0.3 clients.

The CentOs have puppet-0.25.5-1.el5 installed and are working fine to retrieve files.

The Debian boxes have the 0.24.5-3 puppet from the repos, and are failing with the following errors;

```
notice: Starting catalog run
debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
debug: Prefetching apt resources for package
debug: Executing '/usr/bin/dpkg-query -W --showformat '${Status} ${Package} ${Version}\n''
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/dpkg-query -W --showformat '${Status} ${Package} ${Version}\n''
debug: //puppet/Service[puppet]/require: requires Package[puppet]
debug: Calling fileserver.describe
err: //Node[default]/File[/etc/puppet/puppet.conf]: Failed to retrieve current state of resource: Mounts without paths are not usable Could not describe /modules/bpcommon/basenode/etc/puppet/puppet.conf: Mounts without paths are not usable at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp:33
```

The file definitely exists on the fileserver, and is being retrieved and installed by the centos clients.

I am guessing that the earlier version of puppet requires further configuration to work with the file server.

(i have also tested this with a dummy file, test.txt which also fails with the same error, so it does not seem to be related to the fact I am trying to bootstrap /etc/puppet/puppet.conf)

Answer (score 0):

puppet 0.24.5 doesn't support the puppet://modules/modulename/some.file.txt format of specifying the source attribute

this;

source => "puppet://modulename/some.file.txt"

works though.